# How to cover a private method in JUnit Testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

Please help me how am I going to cover the privated method in my class used in a public method.  Whenever I run my JUnit coverage, it says that that private method has a missing branch.

Here is the code that uses that private method:

```
public String addRecord(Record rec) throws IOException {
    GeoPoint geoPoint = locationService.getLocation(rec.getTerminalId());
    if (Objects.isNull(geoPoint)) {
        loggingService.log(this.getClass().toString(), rec.getTerminalId(), "GET LOCATION",
                "No Coordinates found for terminal ID: " + rec.getTerminalId());
        return "No Coordinates found for terminal ID: " + rec.getTerminalId();
    }
    loggingService.log(this.getClass().toString(), rec.getTerminalId(), "GeoPoint",
            "Latitude: " + geoPoint.getLat() + " Longitude: " + geoPoint.getLon());
    format(rec);
    loggingService.log(this.getClass().toString(), rec.getTerminalId(), "addRecord",
            "Formatted Payload" + rec.toString());

    XContentBuilder builder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
    builder.startObject().field("terminalId", rec.getTerminalId())
            .field("status", "D".equals(rec.getStatus()) ? 1 : 0).field("recLocation", rec.getLocation())
            .field("errorDescription", rec.getErrorDescription()).field("lastTranTime", rec.getLastTranTime())
            .field("lastDevStatTime", rec.getLastDevStatTime()).field("errorCode", rec.getErrorCode())
            .field("termBrcode", rec.getTermBrcode()).timeField("@timestamp", new Date())
            .latlon("location", geoPoint.getLat(), geoPoint.getLon()).endObject();

    IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(prop.getEsIndex(), prop.getEsType(), rec.getTerminalId())
            .source(builder);
    IndexResponse response = client.index(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    loggingService.log(this.getClass().toString(), rec.getTerminalId(), TraceLog.SUCCESSFUL_PUSH_TO_ELASTIC_SEARCH,
            util.mapToJsonString(rec));

    return response.getResult().name();
}
```

This is the the private method:

```
private Record format(Record rec) {
    if (rec.getLocation() == null) {
        rec.setLocation("");
    }
    if (rec.getTermBrcode() == null) {
        rec.setTermBrcode("");
    }
    if (rec.getErrorDescription() == null) {
        rec.setErrorDescription("");
    }
    return rec;
}
```

This is my Junit code:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws ParseException, IOException {

    client = mock(RestHighLevelClient.class);
    indexRequest = mock(IndexRequest.class);
    indexResponse = mock(IndexResponse.class);

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    rec= new Record();
    rec.setLocation("location");
    rec.setStatus("U");
    rec.setErrorCode("222");
    rec.setErrorDescription("STATUS");
    rec.setLastDevStatTime("02-02-2020");
    rec.setLastTranTime("02-02-2020");
    rec.setTerminalId("123");
    rec.setTermBrcode("111");

    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(client, "client", restClient);
}

@Test
public void testAddRecordIsNull()
        throws IOException, NumberFormatException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    Mockito.when(locationService.getLocation(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(null);
    elasticsearchService.addRecord(rec);
    assertThat(1).isEqualTo(1);
}

@Test
public void testFormat() throws IOException {
    rec = new Record();
    rec.setLocation(null);
    rec.setStatus(null);
    rec.setErrorCode(null);
    rec.setErrorDescription(null);
    rec.setLastDevStatTime(null);
    rec.setLastTranTime(null);
    rec.setTerminalId(null);
    rec.setTermBrcode(null);
    elasticsearchService.addRecord(rec);
    //ReflectionTestUtils.invokeMethod(ElasticsearchService.class, "addAtmStatusRecord", rec);
    Mockito.when(elasticsearchService.addRecord(null)).thenReturn("");
    //elasticsearchService.addRecord(atm);
    //Mockito.when(locationService.getLocation(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(atm);
    //elasticsearchService.addRecord(null);
    assertThat(1).isEqualTo(1);
}
```

Please help me on where am I missing on my JUnit to cover the private method 'format'.  Any help will be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Don't test private methods. Test the public API.

Answer (score 0):

In `testFormat`, if `elasticsearchService.addRecord` is being tested, it shouldn't mocked. i.e. Remove `Mockito.when(elasticsearchService.addRecord(null)).thenReturn("");`

What should be mocked are the services / dependencies used in the method. e.g. `loggingService`

xxx

Update #1: EclEmma is telling you that the body of the if statements are red. This means that `testAddRecordIsNull` is not configured correctly. It is passing a Record object that has values. Instead of passing `rec`, pass `new Record()`. This assumes that the attributes of the new Record has default values of `null`. If you need to have a Record that has values for other attributes, create a new record accordingly.

Comment: I removed that line of code but it is still missing 1 branch from my coverage.

Comment: @Ronald Which branch is it? Are you using Eclipse? You can check branch coverage using the EclEmma plugin.

Comment: I cannot check the missing branch of my private method using EclEmma.  I researched about it, it says that pinpointing that branch is not included in the plugin.  Or I don't know if I am not updated or something.

Comment: @Ronald Run EclEmma on the whole test class. After that, check the class you are testing. You will see some colors (green, yellow, red). That will help you identify which branches are not covered.

Comment: in all 3 if statement, it is all highlighted with yellow indicating that it is missing 1 branch. And the body of all if statement is highlighted with red.  I think it is the rec.set... body of all 3 if statement is the missing branch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! I finally found the solution.

```
@Test
public void testFormat() throws IOException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
    rec= new Record();
    rec.setLocation(null);
    rec.setStatus(null);
    rec.setErrorCode(null);
    rec.setErrorDescription(null);
    rec.setLastDevStatTime(null);
    rec.setLastTranTime(null);
    rec.setTerminalId(null);
    rec.setTermBrcode(null);

    java.lang.reflect.Method method = ElasticsearchService.class.getDeclaredMethod("format", Record.class);
    method.setAccessible(true);
    Record output = (Record) method.invoke(es, rec);
    assertEquals(output, rec);

}
```

Reflection is the key.  Sharing it here so others running on the same issue might have this for assistance.  Thanks.